# Fetching column names with data in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am building a war file where I don't want to maintain model files and hbm files.

I want to build generic methods for CRUD operations, maintain a properties file outside of the war having constants with queries.

Now when the user makes the request passing in the constant of the query , the query should be read from the properties file and executed in the generic methods for the CRUD operations and result be returned.

Now here I am facing an issue, when fetching data from the database the data is fetched successfully but I am not getting the column names along with the data. So how can I fetch the column names along with the data fetched.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with hibernate or JPA?

Comment: Try using a `javax.persistence.Tuple` as the result class of the query. All JPA providers are supposed to support that as a result class. That way you can get column names. Since you dont post HOW you are invoking a query there is nothing specific to add

Answer (score 0):

You must use ResultSetMetaData: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html

Call getMetaData() on the resultset. Here's an example

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    String name = metaData.getColumnName(i);
}
```